# Encapsulating inner class and acessing outside in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inner-classes, encapsulation

I have these classes, one is a model, other is Listener and the third one is an Util class. I want to access Terrains by the variable map in the first one, but don't want public access to the inner class Terrain. Is there any way to do it?

> It prints *error CS0052: Inconsistent accessibility: field type
>   System.Collections.Generic.List is less
>   accessible than field `MapaMundiInfoScript.map'*

```
public class MapaMundiInfoScript : MonoBehaviour {

public static bool changeInMap= false;       
public static List<Terrain>map = new List<Terrain>();


void Start(){
    Terrain terrain = new Terrain(0,0);
    Terrain.TerrainPart initialPart = new Terrain.TerrainPart(20,20,0,0);
    terrain.terrainParts.Add (initialPart);
    map.Add(terrain);
    changeInMap=true;
}
class Terrain{
        int XPosition;
        int ZPosition;
        public List <TerrainPart> terrainParts = new List<TerrainPart> ();

        public Terrain(int XPosition, int ZPosition){
            this.XPosition=XPosition; this.ZPosition=ZPosition;
        }

        public class TerrainPart
        {
            int XSize;
            int ZSize;
            int XPosition;
            int ZPosition;

            TerrainPartReturn ReturnTerrainPart(int num1,int num2,int num3,int num4)
            {
                return new TerrainPart (num1,num2,num3,num4);
            }

            public TerrainPart(int XSize,int ZSize,int XPosition,int ZPosition){
                 this.XSize = XSize;
                 this.ZSize = ZSize;
                 this.XPosition=XPosition;
                this.ZPosition =ZPosition;
                 }
             }
            }


public class MapListener : MonoBehaviour {

void Update () {

    if (MapaMundiInfoScript.changeInMap) {
        foreach(MapaMundiInfoScript.Terrain terrain in MapaMundiInfoScript.mapMundi)
        {
            foreach(terrain.terrainPart terrainPart in terrain.terrainParts)
            {
        RegionDraw.Draw(terrainPart);
            }
        }
MapaMundiInfoScript.changeInMap = false;
    }    
}


public class RegionDraw
{
/***
Implementantion Draw Method
***/
}
```

Comment: `public static List<Terrain>map = new List<Terreno>();` is syntactically not correct

Comment: @Oxymoron I translated all the code to English, forgot this part, fixed, thanks.

Comment: you may want to use a text editor to find/replace, because that wasn't the only isntance. `Terrain.TerrainPart initialPart = new Terreno.TerrainPart(20,20,0,0);` for example

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reference a private class as a public property. You will need to have the class public for public access. Consider making your properties and methods `private`, `private protected`, `internal` etc.

If you need to provide read only attributes, you can use public getters and private setters, etc. If you need to prevent the execution of some methods consider setting those to private, etc. The class can be public while still locking down properties and methods inside the class. Consider what it is that you actually need to expose.

Answer (score 2):

You could also expose the functionality of these hidden classes through interfaces

```
public interface ITerrain
{
    List<ITerrainPart> TerrainParts { get; }

    ITerrainPart CreateTerrainPart(int XSize, int ZSize, int XPosition, int ZPosition);
}

public interface ITerrainPart
{
    // ...
}
```

Implement them like this

```
private class Terrain : ITerrain
{
    int XPosition;
    int ZPosition;

    public List<ITerrainPart> TerrainParts { get; }  = new List<ITerrainPart>();

    public Terrain(int XPosition, int ZPosition)
    {
        this.XPosition = XPosition; this.ZPosition = ZPosition;
    }

    public ITerrainPart CreateTerrainPart(int XSize, int ZSize, int XPosition,
                                          int ZPosition)
    {
        return new TerrainPart(XSize, ZSize, ZPosition, ZPosition);
    }

    private class TerrainPart : ITerrainPart
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Your listener can then draw like this (after changing the parameter type of `Draw` to `ITerrainPart`):

```
void Update()
{

    if (MapaMundiInfoScript.changeInMap) {
        foreach (ITerrain terrain in MapaMundiInfoScript.map) {
            foreach (ITerrainPart terrainPart in terrain.TerrainParts) {
                RegionDraw.Draw(terrainPart);
            }
        }
        MapaMundiInfoScript.changeInMap = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let MapaMundiInfoScript have a method DrawTerrain() and let Terrain have a method DrawParts.  Should you end up with to many incoherent methods in MapaMundiInfoScript, you might want to use a visitor.